# how to compare only by date (without time) in jooq?

Tags: java, sql, kotlin, time, jooq

I have column with type `timestamp with time zone`. The table contains the following value "2022-06-30 22:56:29.183764 +00:00". I want to do a date-only search.

**how to compare only by date (without  time) in jooq?**

I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
.where(MY_TABLE.UPDATED_AT.cast(LocalDate::class.java).eq(cashDate))
```

where `cashDate = "2022-06-30"`

Comment: How do you define a date? The beginning and ending of a day differ by time zone. Do you want the date as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds? Or do you want "2022-06-30" as seen in Tokyo, Japan? Or in Toledo Ohio US?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide your own converter for the conversion you want to have between `Timestamp` and `LocalDate`.

Check a [similar](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) example from `jooq`.

In your case it would be

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import org.jooq.Converter;

    public class LocalDateConverter implements Converter<Timestamp, LocalDate> {
    
        @Override
        public LocalDate from(Timestamp t) {
            return t == null ? null : t.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        }
    
        @Override
        public Timestamp to(LocalDate u) {
            return u == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(u.atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT));
        }
    
        @Override
        public Class<Timestamp> fromType() {
            return Timestamp.class;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Class<LocalDate> toType() {
            return LocalDate.class;
        }
    }
```

In the above example I have used `ZoneId.systemDefault()` for the conversion of `timestamp` to `localdate` and also `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT` for conversion of `localdate` to `timestamp`. This might be a bit dangerous and should be investigated from you if another specific zoneId should be used for your systems to work as expected.

Then you can use it as

```
.where(MY_TABLE.UPDATED_AT.asConvertedDataType(new LocalDateConverter()).eq(cashDate))
```